# Convert comma separated String into Json string

Tags: java, json, string

```
String input = "Vish,Path,123456789";
```

Expected output as Json string, and thread safe = **{"name":"Vish","surname":"Path","mobile":"123456789"}**

I tried by using

```
 GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder(); 
 Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

But every time I'm creating new Object -

```
MappingObject[] studentArray = new MappingObject[1]; 
studentArray[0] = new MappingObject("Vish","Path","123456789");
```

I separated this comma separated string by using split()

```
 System.out.println("JSON "+gson.toJson(studentArray));
```

Comment: and what problem are you facing?

Comment: @sidgate I tried by using GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create(); But every time I'm creating new Object -        MappingObject[] studentArray = new MappingObject[1];
          studentArray[0] = new MappingObject("Vish","Path","123456789"); I separated this comma separated string by using split() 
System.out.println("JSON "+gson.toJson(studentArray)); So, I want to create single object only even if I work with multiple student and that conversion process should be thread safe as well.

Comment: Use JSONObject constructor with Map<String,String> as argument

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use any  library then you have to split string by comma and make a new `String`.

```
String input = "Vish,Path,123456789";
String[] values=input.split("[,]");
StringBuffer json = new StringBuffer();// StringBuffer is Thread Safe
json.append("{")
    .append("\"name\": \"").append(values[0]).append("\",")
    .append("\"surname\": \"").append(values[1]).append("\",")
    .append("\"mobile\": \"").append(values[2]).append("\"")
    .append("}");
System.out.println(json.toString());
```

Output :

> {"name": "Vish","surname": "Path","mobile": "123456789"}

If you want to use library then you will achive this by `Jackson`. Simple make a class and make json by it.

```
public class Person {
  private String name;
  private String surname;
  private String mobile;

  // ... getters and Setters
}

String input = "Vish,Path,123456789";
String[] values=input.split("[,]");
Person person = new Person(values[0],values[1],values[2]);// Assume you have All Argumets Constructor in specified order  
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); //com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(person);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a Map:

```
Map<String,String> jsonMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
jsonMap.put("name","Vish");
jsonMap.put("surname","Path");
jsonMap.put("mobile","123456789");
```

Then use com.google.gson JSONObject:
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonMap);